# How to solve a system of inequality and equality systematically?

Tags: inequality, systems-of-equations

How to solve this system of inequalities and equalities systematically:

$\begin{array}{l}
\left\{ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
{\frac{x}{{2x + 3y}} + \frac{y}{{y + z}} + \frac{z}{{x + z}} = \frac{{34}}{{33}}}\\
{1 \le x \le 4}\\
{1 \le y \le 4}\\
{1 \le z \le 4}\\
{x \ge y}\\
{x \ge z}
\end{array}} \right.\\
 \Leftrightarrow \left\{ {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}
{x = 4}\\
{y = 1}\\
{z = 2}
\end{array}} \right.
\end{array}$

I got this answer from Mathematica, but I am not so sure how to do it manually.

Please help me with this, thank you for your enthusiasm !

Comment: Can you please add context about why this is relevant to this community and likely to be useful to others in the future?  Part of our mission is to build an archive of knowledge that will be useful to others as well.  You can do that by providing the motivation or context in which you encountered this problem, and by showing your progress in trying to solve it yourself.

Comment: Are you only interested in integer solutions, or real-numbered solutions?

Comment: Thank you so much real solution is ok

Comment: For future reference, please don't put clarifications in the comments.  Instead, we prefer that you [edit] your question so it contains all relevant information, in the post itself, and improve it to address the feedback that was provided.  Thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Multiply by $(2x+3y)(y+z)(x+z)$ to clear fractions, collect terms, and thereby conclude that:

$$\frac{x}{2x + 3y} + \frac{y}{y + z} + \frac{z}{x + z} - \frac{34}{33} =
\frac{31 x^2 y - 35 x^2 z - 3 x y^2 - 5 x y z + 31 x z^2 + 96 y^2 z - 3 y z^2}{33 (2 x + 3 y) (x + z) (y + z)}.$$

It is easy to see that $(2 x + 3 y) (x + z) (y + z) > 0$ for your range of $x,y,z$.

Therefore, your problem amounts to finding $x,y,z$ that satisfy $f(x,y,z)=0$, where

$$f(x,y,z) = 31 x^2 y - 35 x^2 z - 3 x y^2 - 5 x y z + 31 x z^2 + 96 y^2 z - 3 y z^2,$$

subject to $1 \le y \le x \le 4$, $1 \le z \le x \le 4$.

Writing $f(x,y,z) = p(x,y) + q(x,y) z + r(x,y) z^2$ for appropriate polynomials $p(x,y),q(x,y),r(x,y)$, we can then apply the quadratic formula (w.r.t. $z$) to obtain

$$z = \frac{35 x^2 + 5 x y - 96 y^2 \pm \sqrt{s(x,y)}}{62 x - 6 y},$$

where

$$s(x,y) = 1225 x^4 - 3494 x^3 y - 5951 x^2 y^2 - 996 x y^3 + 9216 y^4.$$

Equivalently, $s(x,y) = y^4 \cdot t(x/y)$ where

$$t(w) = 1225 w^4 - 3494 w^3 - 5951 w^2 - 996 w + 9216.$$

We have $t(w) = (w-4)(w-1)(1225w^2 + 2631w + 2304)$, so the only real roots of $t(w)$ are at $w=1$ and $w=4$.  We have $t(w)<0$ for $1<w<4$, so this region will not lead to any valid solutions for the original problem, as then the formula for $z$ above gives imaginary values for $z$, which are not allowable.  Therefore, we must have either $w=1$ or $w=4$, which corresponds to solutions where $x/y=1$ or $x/y=4$.  We can consider each of those two cases separately:

- If $x/y=1$:  Plugging in $y=x$ into the formula above, we discover

  $$z = \frac{35 x^2 + 5 x^2 - 96 x^2}{62 x - 6 x} = -x.$$

  Therefore, this case is impossible, as it is inconsistent with the requirement that $z \ge 1$.
- If $x/y=4$: This is only possible if $x=4$, $y=1$.  Plugging into the formula for $z$ above, we find $z=2$.  This is the solution in your question.